# I'm unable to login with GUI

Tags: login

I am able to login in through the terminal without any problem but when I enter my password in the login box(GUI) it doesn't show any error, just that is prompts me again to enter my credentials. I tried to enter other passwords but it gives me error.

This issue started after I created another user account on my system. Any ideas how cant I sort it out?

Comment: Do you get any output when you log in through tty (a.k.a. 'terminal')?

Comment: it works fine, the steps i follow now to login are: 1.login as guest, CTRL+ALT+F2 to switch to CLI, login with user and pass and it works

Comment: Does any of the solutions to the question linked below solve your problem? I think you're experiencing a login loop which is a common problem caused by wrong usage, but which is usually easily fixable.

Comment: You don't need to login as guest to use a tty. Just press Ctrl+Alt+F1...6 when you are in the login screen.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many causes why that happened but here are a couple of things you can try.

1. Login into tty with your user (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>)
2. Type `sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /home/[username]`  and try logging in (return using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>)

That should change .Xauthority permissions to yourself.

If that doesn't work try `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp`

If none of the above works you can try:

- `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
- Reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: Hello guys, seems that i messed up something during my experimental exercise of creating/modifying usernames available for GUI login. After trying all the commands i found on forum i reinstalled Linux and everything works fine! good luck